# Python integer variable scope vs set scope

Tags: python, scope

In the following code if I define `current` in the for loop as an integer then during the call in dfs function `current += 1` will error out with "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'current' referenced before assignment".

```
def numIslands(grid):
    def dfs(i,j):
        if i < 0 or j < 0 or i >= len(grid) or j >= len(grid[0]):
            return
        if(i,j) in visited or not grid[i][j]:
            return
        current += 1
        dfs(i+1,j)
        dfs(i-1,j)
        dfs(i,j+1)
        dfs(i,j-1)
        
    res = 0
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        for j in range(len(grid[0])):
            current = 0
            dfs(i,j)
            if current:
                res = max(current, res)
    return res
```

But if I define `current` as a set like `current = set()` and do `current.add((i,j))` in dfs instead of `current += 1` then there's no issue. Can someone explain the reason?

Comment: Can you provide a *minimal* example? As far as I can see, the code never assigns to `current_island`, so it’s no surprise that *that* is unassigned. As for `current`, I suspect that the solution as adding a `nonlocal` declaration, but as the question stands, it is hard to be sure.

Comment: `+=` involves *reassigning* the variable. That's a special case and involves determining variable *scope*. `current.add(...)` doesn't reassign anything and just calls a method on an object.

Answer (score -1):

The "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'current_island' referenced before assignment" error occurs in Python when you try to use a local variable before it has been assigned a value. To fix this error, you need to make sure that the variable 'current_island' is assigned a value before you try to use it. Declare  `current_island = False` before accessing it.

Try below code:

```
def numIslands(grid):
    def dfs(i,j):
        if i < 0 or j < 0 or i >= len(grid) or j >= len(grid[0]):
            return
        if(i,j) in visited or not grid[i][j]:
            return
        visited.add((i,j))
        current += 1
        dfs(i+1,j)
        dfs(i-1,j)
        dfs(i,j+1)
        dfs(i,j-1)
        
    visited = set()
    res = 0
    current_island = False
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        for j in range(len(grid[0])):
            current = 0
            dfs(i,j)
            if current_island:
                res = max(len(current_island), res)
    return res
```

Comment: sorry wrong variable name, I edited the question to eliminate the confusion